# Transmit - word choice

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is **transmit** an appropriate verb to use in this sentence?

I am a 19-year-old girl who has a passion for young people since they transmit me positive energy.

Comment: If you want to use _transmit_, the object of the verb is _energy_, not _me_, so it would be better to say _they transmit positive energy to me_.

Answer (score 1):

"Transmit ... to me" as mentioned by @KateBunting is OK.

If you want to make a general statement, then the most common ways of putting it would be:

*... because they  **radiate** / **exude** / **give you** / **give off** positive energy.*

It's really about "you", then, as I think was suggested in @DialFrost's now-deleted answer:

*They **give me** positive energy.*